# Why can't I trigger default click after acquiring more parameters for an href via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to search for all vendors within a mileage radius, but in order to do that I need coordinates for the address for which I'm searching.  It's not feasible to grab these coordinates up front because the map search isn't used all that often.

So, what I want to do is grab the coordinates from Google Maps *when the link is clicked* (if we haven't gotten them already), *then* continue with the default browser behavior.  This is the code I have to accomplish this:

**HTML**

```html
<a href="/vendors/search" target="_blank" class="vendorMapSearch" 
   data-miles-radius="50" data-address="@Model.Address.SingleLine()" 
   data-customer-name="@Model.CustomerName" data-customer-id="@Model.CustomerId"
   data-service-on="@Model.ServiceOn">Vendor Map Search</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.vendorMapSearch', function (e) {
    console.log('HANDLE CLICK');
    var $target = $(e.target),
        data = $target.data();

    if (!data.latitude || !data.longitude) {
        console.log('HITTING GOOGLE MAPS');
        var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&sensor=false&address=' + data.address;

        $.getJSON(url, function (resp) {
            console.log('response received');
            if (!resp.results.length) {
                $('<div>Could not find coordinates for the address entered.</div>');
                return;
            }

            $target.data('latitude', resp.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            $target.data('longitude', resp.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

            $target.attr('href', $target.attr('href') + '?' + $.param($target.data()));

            $target.trigger('coordinatesAcquired');
        });

        return false;
    }

    console.log('RETURNING TRUE');
    return true;
});

$(document).on('coordinatesAcquired', function() {
    console.log('COORDINATES ACQUIRED');
    $('a.vendorMapSearch').trigger('click');
});
```

It gives this output:

```
HANDLE CLICK 
HITTING GOOGLE MAPS 
XHR finished loading: (blah blah)
COORDINATES ACQUIRED
HANDLE CLICK 
RETURNING TRUE
```

It looks correct to me, but the behavior is that it does not trigger the default link browser behavior (in Chrome at least) unless I click the link a second time.  Anyone know what's up with this?

Answer (score 1):

Trigger doesn't really click on the `a`, it just launch the listener. The default behavior is triggering, but here what you can do. You can check in the event handler if the click is triggered and then manually change the page :

```
if(e.isTrigger) window.location = this.href
```

or to open in another window :

```
if(e.isTrigger) window.open(this.href, '_blank ')
```

Comment: Unfortunately (and I will update the question shortly to explain this), it's target="_blank", and I believe there's no way to reliably trigger a new tab via JS.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Well, the is `if(e.isTrigger) window.open(this.href, '_blank ')`, but it open somehow in an other window, not tab. You can learn more about window here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

Comment: `window.open($('a.vendorMapSearch').attr('href'));` will open in new tab, no need for the second parameter `_blank`. http://jsfiddle.net/ekLsL/1/

Comment: @RaphaelDDL It depends on your browser settings.  By default, it opens a tab in IE, but a window in Chrome.  There's no way to reliably open a new tab via JS.

Comment: @JoshKodroff True to 'no way to reliably open a new tab via js'. But anyways, I tested on all browsers (IE9, Chrome 30, Chrome Canary 31, Safari 5.1, Firefox 23 and 24, Opera 12.16) with default settings and only Safari opened on new window, all others opened on new tab.

Comment: Chrome (on Windows) opens for me in a new window.  I think that'll actually be good enough for my users anyway as I believe they all use IE 10.